# What are my rights as an assignee to my dads patent invention

Tags: williamconger

My mom told me that my dad invented the first pick proof lock and he left me as an assignee to the patent I'm wondering what my role is now as far as any royalties or any compensation from his invention

Comment: Do you know the patent number? We can look it up and see if the patent is expired or not. Is it perhaps US4112820? If so, that patent expired quite a while ago. https://patents.google.com/patent/US4112820A/en?q=(lock)&inventor=william+conger

Comment: People have been patenting “pick proof” locks since at least 1857 https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/02/a7/c8/8f135a7e7b6c33/US17293.pdf

Comment: When did your father invented/patented it? For how long did you or your family paid the renewal fees?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make the assumption that, based on your tag, your father's name  is William Conger. I did a search and only found one lock patent with William Conger listed as an inventor. It is [US4112820](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4112820A/en?q=(lock)&inventor=william%20conger). This patent was granted on September 9th, 1978 and expired on November 23rd, 1997.

This means that the patent is no longer enforceable and anyone can use the invention described by it. This is the basic deal with patents. In return for a limited period of exclusivity, you give your invention to the world. Therefore there is no more potential for licensing from this patent. It is neat that your father was an inventor and you should have pride in his achievement.